# input not working in python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python.

I was reading a tutorial online, the author used `str = input()`, and then he enters a sentence. After that, he get the input string stored in str.  However, when I was trying `str = input()` in my python shell, it does not work. Here is the error:

```
>>> a = input()
test sentence

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    a = input()
  File "<string>", line 1
    test sentence
            ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Can you tell me why is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a = input() test sentence` is not a valid code.

you can write comments with `#` character.

edit : what version of python are you using? try `raw_input` instead of `input`.

the difference between `input` and `raw_input` in python 2:

[`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) : reads whatever user wrote by newline and stores it into `str`

[`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) : reads whatever user wrote and **evalutes** that input

`raw_input` became `input` in python 3.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of `input` has changed between Python 2 and Python 3. In Python 2, `input` actually evaluated whatever you entered as Python code. So when you enter something that is syntactically not correct in Python, then you get such an error. In addition, there is `raw_input` which just takes whatever input comes and returns it in a string.

Now because the evaluating `input` is not really that useful (and eval is evil), the behaviour of `input` got replaced by Python 2’s `raw_input` in Python 3.

The author of your tutorial most likely used Python 3, where `input` behaves like `raw_input` did in Python 2. If you use Python 2, just use `raw_input` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using `input()`, it expects valid Python code. You get a `SyntaxError` because `test sentence` is not valid Python.

Therefore, try using `raw_input()` (which returns a string) OR do this:

```
>>> a = input()
'test sentence' # by entering it as a string, it is evaluable
```

References:

- [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=raw_input#raw_input)
- [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=raw_input#input)

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, `raw_input(...)` will return whatever was typed in as a string. `input(...)` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(...))` (**very dangerous!!**). `eval` evaluates its argument as Python code and returns the result, so `input` expects properly-formatted Python code. You should **never** use `input` or `eval` in Python 2 as it is a security risk; use `raw_input` instead.

In Python 3, `input(...)` returns whatever was typed in as a string.